# How to send HTTP request using urllib2 with proxy

Tags: python, urllib2

I want to send HTTP request using urllib2 with proxy. The proxy will be in the database and each time send HTTP request sent by getting the proxy IP from table.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the syntax youre looking for:

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '177.124.160.6'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/search')
```

Alternatively in Python 2.7 requests library you can do:

```
requests.request(
        method="GET",
        url='https://www.google.com/search',
        params= params,
        headers=headers,
        proxies =  proxy)
```

Where each input is an object with key value pairs

Comment: But I need to get proxy from a database table.

Comment: So then its as simple as performing a database query for your proxy and  plugging that in to the above code. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Without taking a look at your database its impossible for someone to provide you with the query syntax..

Comment: You should query the database for the proxy IP, then pass it into ProxyHandler. What do you mean you cant 'append' the IP to the request. What type of error are you getting and when?

Comment: Thank You, I was not passing the right column of the table in proxyhandler.